# TAO+ACE ROOTPOA

Tags: c++, corba, tao

For notification client in c++ (TAO), we are registering the reference (register_initial_reference) with the RootPOA. Is there any other type of POA exists other than RootPOA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is support for child POAs, see the [CORBA specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/CORBA/Current/) for details about the POA or see the huge amount of examples/tests that are part of TAO, for example in the TAO/tests/POA directory